# I am scanning the code using HP fortify. I am getting Path Manipulation error when I try to open the File

Tags: c#, fortify

I am getting the issue when I use "FileSystem.FileOpen". I am posting the code below. I am getting the path from the user and I have already validated the path before opening the file. Still I am getting the same File Manipulation Issue in HP Fortify.

```
if ((File.Exists(moFrmIntComplaint.lblFilePath.Text)) && moFrmIntComplaint.lblFilePath.Text.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) >= 0)
                {
                    sFilePath = moFrmIntComplaint.lblFilePath.Text;
                    sFileName = Path.GetFileName(sFilePath);//moFrmIntComplaint.lblFileName.Text;
                    sFileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(sFilePath);
                }
                if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(sFilePath.Trim(' ')) == false) && (File.Exists(moFrmIntComplaint.lblFilePath.Text)) && (moFrmIntComplaint.lblFilePath.Text.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) >= 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(moFrmIntComplaint.lblFilePath.Text))
                {
                    lFilePtr = FileSystem.FreeFile();
                    FileSystem.FileOpen(lFilePtr, sFilePath, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default, -1);
                    lFileSize = (int)FileSystem.LOF(lFilePtr);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have modified the post, hope the problem is clear now.

Comment: Please help, stuck here for two days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your validation logic to see if you can pass a file named:

`../../../cmdshell.aspx`

or

`../../../web.config`

Path manipulation is all about redirecting the server to an undesirable location for file reads and writes.  Don't rely on filesystem permissions.

Comment: The code only accepts pdf files. I am checking else where in code to see if the file to be opened is pdf or not. But still I am getting Path Manipulation warning from Hp Fortify.

Comment: The file validation is a different Fortify category.  The key with Path Manip is to guarantee you can't change the location.  With Path Manip vulns if you can use ../ or figure out subdirectories you can make bad things happen.